# Counting number of char in a line in C

Tags: c, file-io

I'd like to find the number of character in each line using C program. It would work fine if I'm having single statement in a single line. But, if multiple statements means, it adds a 0 following it. How could I modify my code to achieve what I need? Thanks in advance.

```
fp=fopen("chumma.c","r");
while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF)
{
    cn++;
    if((c=='\n') || (c==';'))
    {
         if((cn-1)==0)
            em++;
        n++;
        printf("\nNo. of char in line %d : %d\n",n,(cn-1));
        ll[n-1]=cn-1;
        cn=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use `fgets()`.

Comment: @Nick But, if I use fgets, I can't count the number of characters in that line. I need to calculate that.

Comment: use `strlen` after `fgets` for counting characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the following code seems a little round about, yet it works. If anyone can simplify it, let me know. Thanks.

```
while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF)
{
  cn++;
  if(c==';')
  {
    n++;
    printf("\nNo. of char in line %d : %d\n",n,cn);
    ll[n-1]=cn;
    cn=0;
    flag=1;
  }

  if(c=='\n')
  {
    if(flag==1)
    {
      flag=0;
      cn--;
    }

    else{
      if((cn-1)==0)
         em++;
      n++;
      printf("\nNo. of char in line %d : %d\n",n,(cn-1));
      ll[n-1]=cn-1;
      cn=0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, I didn't compile it but it should work.

```
char buffer[1024];
fp=fopen("chumma.c","r");
while(fgets(buffer, 1024, fp))
{
    n++;
    cn = strlen(buffer);
    printf("\nNo. of char in line %d : %d\n",n,cn);
}
```

Comment: he doesn’t care about knowing the number of characters in a file

Answer (score 0):

With fgets:

```
char buffer[MAX_BUFFER];

fp=fopen("chumma.c","r");
while (fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER, fp)) {
    cn = strnlen(buffer,MAX_BUFFER);
    n++;
    printf("\nNo. of char in line %d : %d\n",n, cn);

}
```

Something like that.

Comment: But, its not working for multiple statements in a single line.

Comment: @Gomathi You can use strtok() to tokenize the line with ';' and find length of each token and sum it up.

Comment: why not use fgetpos and lose the linear-time strlen?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you. I have not compiled though.

```
#define SIZE 1024
char buffer[SIZE];
char * pch;
int cn = 0;

fp=fopen("chumma.c","r");
while (fgets(buffer, SIZE, fp)) 
{
  pch = strtok (buffer,";");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    cn += strnlen(pch,SIZE);
    pch = strtok (NULL, ";");
  }
    n++;
    printf("\nNo. of char in line %d : %d\n",n, cn);
  cn = 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: still the same output, Sir.

Comment: Even now, it didn't consider multiple statements.

Comment: How about `while (strchr(buffer, ';')) cn++` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I really forgot the code but i can still give you a very sound logic which will definately help you. If you have heard about character pointers then no problem.

1) Open the file using fopen.
2) Start a loop till endoffile EOF and fill entire content of file in an array.
3) Create a character pointer with start position of that array and put it inside a loop till '\0' //the ending character of that array.
4) using the value of the pointer in each iteration you can calculate what each element is like (a number or an alphabet --ASCII comparison)

Let me know if that helps